# How can I have filter view load automatically upon opening Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-filter-view

Looking to have my sheet automatically load a filter once it's opened. How can I have it do so?

Comment: Could you please show the way you currently open it? Do you do it manually or use some script or framework? Very sorry but it's unclear for the moment, to think about the solution, so please add some details

Comment: I have a filter saved, but manually have to go under the filter view settings to load it. Is there a script I can use to make it open without having to manually click onto the filter every time I open the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Notice the query parameter `fvid=` at the end of sheet's url.

When you create a filter. That Filter View Id will appear. 
You can have many filter views in the sheet, yours or someone else's. The way to make sure you are opening the sheet with your filter on, is to append the `fvid=` param at the end of the url.

#### Example:

```js
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<YOUR-FILE-ID>/edit#gid=0&fvid=1781225551
```

Comment: I visited the filter's URL as you suggested and bookmarked it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a global filter (the green one):

[image]